# Filtering by Max Date with Two Column Constraint SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I noticed today that one of my queries was returning duplicate values. Here is the query:

```
SELECT  l.po_no, l.item_id, l.date_created
FROM po_line AS l INNER JOIN
    (SELECT   item_id, MAX(date_created) AS maxdate
         FROM        po_line AS l
             GROUP BY item_id) AS md 
             ON l.item_id = md.item_id AND l.date_created = md.maxdate
```

Basically, I'm trying to find the most recent POs limited to 1 per item_id.

When I remove the po_no from the SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT   item_id, MAX(date_created) AS date_created
FROM         po_line
GROUP BY item_id
```

I will only get the most recent date by item_id, where there are no duplicates - which is great!

However, as soon as I ask for the po_no, the query start returning more than 1 row per item_id. If I ask for the most recent date and po_no, not including item_id, it will basically just return the entire list of POs.

I've tried creating a helper table using the query above and joining back on po_line on item_id and date_created... but no matter what I do (left join, right join, inner join, etc.) it will not result in what I'm trying to create.

I basically want the most recent PO limited to only 1 record per item_id. I hope this all makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT l.po_no, l.item_id, l.date_created
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY date_created DESC) as seqnum
      FROM po_line l
     ) l
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You clearly have duplicates in your data.  If you did want the duplicates, you would use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` instead.